# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpsession

While control reaches in `ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();` it gives the mentioned error.

This error occurs while running a job.

I have already tried the suggested answer from other post by incorporating the below in my web.xml file, but issue still issue not resolved.

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

**Complete Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
        at com.hcl.ne.model.DiscoveredProduct.getCreatedOn(DiscoveredProduct.java:158)
        at com.hcl.ne.job.processor.IDSNormalizationProcessor.process(IDSNormalizationProcessor.java:155)
        at com.hcl.ne.job.processor.IDSNormalizationProcessor.process(IDSNormalizationProcessor.java:1)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR: org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step masterStep in job partitionJob
    org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
        at com.hcl.ne.controller.JobController.genericNormalizeFinalData(JobController.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:150)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:523)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherL
    ink.java:955)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**IDSNormalizationProcessor**

```
package com.hcl.ne.job.processor;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

import com.hcl.ne.dao.NormalizeDao;
import com.hcl.ne.dao.NormalizeDaoImpl;
import com.hcl.ne.model.DiscoveredProduct;
import com.hcl.ne.model.FinalNormalizedProduct;
import com.hcl.ne.model.PdtCatalog;

public class IDSNormalizationProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DiscoveredProduct, FinalNormalizedProduct> {

    private Map parameterValues = new HashMap();
    private DataSource dataSource;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    FinalNormalizedProduct normalizedProduct= null;

    private String threadName;

    @Override
    public FinalNormalizedProduct process(DiscoveredProduct argDiscoveredProduct) throws Exception {

    //  System.out.println(threadName);
        NormalizeDao nd = new NormalizeDaoImpl(dataSource);

        String selectedDisPdt = parameterValues.get("discoveredPdt").toString();
        String selectedDisPdtName = parameterValues.get("discoveredPdtName").toString();

        String companyName = "\"" + parameterValues.get("companyName").toString() + "\"";
        String className = "\"" + parameterValues.get("classType").toString() + "\"";
        String companyId =parameterValues.get("companyId").toString();
        String classId = parameterValues.get("classId").toString();
        List<PdtCatalog> listPdtCatalog = nd.listPdtCatalog(companyName,className,companyId,classId, selectedDisPdtName);
        //Removing from here as multiple docs with no values are entered.
        //FinalNormalizedProduct normalizedProduct= new FinalNormalizedProduct();
        normalizedProduct= new FinalNormalizedProduct();
        if(listPdtCatalog != null && listPdtCatalog.size() >0)
        {
            for(PdtCatalog pdtCatalogListData : listPdtCatalog)
            {
                if(pdtCatalogListData.getDisPdtname().equalsIgnoreCase(argDiscoveredProduct.getName()))
                {
                    normalizedProduct.setAttributes(argDiscoveredProduct.getAttributes());
                    normalizedProduct.setNormalizedProductName(pdtCatalogListData.getProductCatalogName());

                    List<Map<String, Object>> attrList = pdtCatalogListData.getPdtCatAttrList();
                    List<Map<String, Object>> noramlizedAttrList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

                    Map<String, Object>[] attrArray = null;
                    if(attrList != null && attrList.size() > 0)
                    {
                        //attrArray = new HashMap[attrList.size()];
                        attrArray = new HashMap[0];
                        Map<String,Object> normalizedAttrMap = new HashMap();
                        for(Map<String, Object> attrMap : attrList)
                        {
                            Set<String> attrKeySet = attrMap.keySet();
                            for(String attrKey : attrKeySet)
                            {

                                /*if(normalizedProduct.getNormalizedAttributes()[0].containsKey(attrKey))
                                {
                                    //normalizedProduct.getAttributes()[0].put(attrKey,attrMap.get(attrKey));
                                    normalizedProduct.getNormalizedAttributes()[0].put(attrKey,attrMap.get(attrKey));


                                }*/
                                if(argDiscoveredProduct.getAttributes()[0].containsKey(attrKey))
                                {
                                    normalizedAttrMap.put(attrKey, attrMap.get(attrKey));                               
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        noramlizedAttrList.add(normalizedAttrMap);
                        /*attrArray = attrList.toArray(attrArray);*/

                    }

                    //normalizedProduct.setNormalizedAttributes(attrArray);
                    //normalizedProduct.setAttributes(attrArray);
                    normalizedProduct.setName(argDiscoveredProduct.getName());
                    normalizedProduct.setClassType(argDiscoveredProduct.getClassType());
                    normalizedProduct.setCompany(argDiscoveredProduct.getCompany());
                    normalizedProduct.setDataset(argDiscoveredProduct.getDataset());
                    Date date = new Date();

                    normalizedProduct.set_id(argDiscoveredProduct.get_id());
                    normalizedProduct.set_rev(argDiscoveredProduct.get_rev());

                    normalizedProduct.setHostName(argDiscoveredProduct.getHostName());
                    normalizedProduct.setSerialNumber(argDiscoveredProduct.getSerialNumber());
                    normalizedProduct.setCreatedOn(argDiscoveredProduct.getCreatedOn());
                    if(noramlizedAttrList.size() >0)
                    {
                        normalizedProduct.setNormalizedAttributes(noramlizedAttrList.toArray(attrArray));
                    }
                    normalizedProduct.setNormalizedOn(dateFormat.format(date));
                    normalizedProduct.setIsNormalized("yes");
                    normalizedProduct.setNe_status("N");



                }
                else
                {
                    normalizedProduct.setAttributes(argDiscoveredProduct.getAttributes());
                    normalizedProduct.setName(argDiscoveredProduct.getName());
                    normalizedProduct.setClassType(argDiscoveredProduct.getClassType());
                    normalizedProduct.setCompany(argDiscoveredProduct.getCompany());
                    normalizedProduct.setDataset(argDiscoveredProduct.getDataset());
                    Date date = new Date();

                    normalizedProduct.set_id(argDiscoveredProduct.get_id());
                    normalizedProduct.set_rev(argDiscoveredProduct.get_rev());

                    normalizedProduct.setHostName(argDiscoveredProduct.getHostName());
                    normalizedProduct.setSerialNumber(argDiscoveredProduct.getSerialNumber());
                    normalizedProduct.setCreatedOn(argDiscoveredProduct.getCreatedOn());
                    normalizedProduct.setIsNormalized("yes");
                    normalizedProduct.setNormalizedOn(dateFormat.format(date));
                    normalizedProduct.setNe_status("N");
                    //normalizedProduct.setNoMappingFound("NO Mapping Found");
                }

            }

        }
        //if Only one pdt is selected which is not mapped also.
        else
        {
            normalizedProduct.setAttributes(argDiscoveredProduct.getAttributes());
            normalizedProduct.setName(argDiscoveredProduct.getName());
            normalizedProduct.setClassType(argDiscoveredProduct.getClassType());
            normalizedProduct.setCompany(argDiscoveredProduct.getCompany());
            normalizedProduct.setDataset(argDiscoveredProduct.getDataset());
            Date date = new Date();         
            normalizedProduct.set_id(argDiscoveredProduct.get_id());
            normalizedProduct.set_rev(argDiscoveredProduct.get_rev());          
            normalizedProduct.setHostName(argDiscoveredProduct.getHostName());
            normalizedProduct.setSerialNumber(argDiscoveredProduct.getSerialNumber());
            normalizedProduct.setCreatedOn(argDiscoveredProduct.getCreatedOn());
            normalizedProduct.setNormalizedOn(dateFormat.format(date));
            normalizedProduct.setIsNormalized("yes");
            normalizedProduct.setNe_status("N");

        }




        return normalizedProduct;
    }
    public Map getParameterValues() {
        return parameterValues;
    }
    public void setParameterValues(Map parameterValues) {
        this.parameterValues = parameterValues;
    }
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }
    public void setThreadName(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }
}
```

**Discovered Product Model**

```
package com.hcl.ne.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import com.hcl.ne.service.util.CommonUtility;

public class DiscoveredProduct {

    private String _id;
    private String _rev;
    private String name;
    private String productCatalogName;
    private String normalizedProductName;
    private String domain;
    private String desc;
    private String product;
    private String company;
    private String dataset;
    private String classType;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes[];
    private List<Map<String, Object>> attributes2;
    private String hostName;
    private String serialNumber;
    private String createdOn;
    private String qulRuleId;
    private String classId;
    private String companyId;
    private String selectedDiscoveredPdt;
    private int pageSize;
    private String isNormalized;
    private String ne_status;
    private Map<String, Object> normalizedAttributes[];
    private String normalizedOn;
    private String rolledBackOn;
    private String approvedOn;

    public String getNe_status() {
        return ne_status;
    }

    public void setNe_status(String ne_status) {
        this.ne_status = ne_status;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_rev() {
        return _rev;
    }

    public void set_rev(String _rev) {
        this._rev = _rev;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getDataset() {
        return dataset;
    }

    public void setDataset(String dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    public String getClassType() {
        return classType;
    }

    public void setClassType(String classType) {
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    public String getProductCatalogName() {
        return productCatalogName;
    }

    public void setProductCatalogName(String productCatalogName) {
        this.productCatalogName = productCatalogName;
    }

    public Map<String, Object>[] getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, Object>[] attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public String getCreatedOn() {
        long epochDate = Long.parseLong(createdOn);
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();

        String timeZone = (String) session.getAttribute("timeZone");
        String dateFormat = (String) session.getAttribute("dateFormat");
        String offSet = (String) session.getAttribute("offSetValue");
        String resultDate = CommonUtility.getDateInGMT(epochDate, timeZone, dateFormat, offSet);
        return resultDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getAttributes2() {
        return attributes2;
    }

    public void setAttributes2(List<Map<String, Object>> attributes2) {
        this.attributes2 = attributes2;
    }

    public String getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }

    public void setClassId(String classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }

    public String getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public String getSelectedDiscoveredPdt() {
        return selectedDiscoveredPdt;
    }

    public void setSelectedDiscoveredPdt(String selectedDiscoveredPdt) {
        this.selectedDiscoveredPdt = selectedDiscoveredPdt;
    }

    public String getQulRuleId() {
        return qulRuleId;
    }

    public void setQulRuleId(String qulRuleId) {
        this.qulRuleId = qulRuleId;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public String getIsNormalized() {
        return isNormalized;
    }

    public void setIsNormalized(String isNormalized) {
        this.isNormalized = isNormalized;

    }

    public String getNormalizedProductName() {
        return normalizedProductName;
    }

    public void setNormalizedProductName(String normalizedProductName) {
        this.normalizedProductName = normalizedProductName;
    }

    public Map<String, Object>[] getNormalizedAttributes() {
        return normalizedAttributes;
    }

    public void setNormalizedAttributes(Map<String, Object>[] normalizedAttributes) {
        this.normalizedAttributes = normalizedAttributes;
    }

    public String getNormalizedOn() {
        return normalizedOn;
    }

    public void setNormalizedOn(String normalizedOn) {
        this.normalizedOn = normalizedOn;
    }

    public String getRolledBackOn() {
        return rolledBackOn;
    }

    public void setRolledBackOn(String rolledBackOn) {
        this.rolledBackOn = rolledBackOn;
    }

    public String getApprovedOn() {
        return approvedOn;
    }

    public void setApprovedOn(String approvedOn) {
        this.approvedOn = approvedOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286675/scope-session-is-not-active-for-the-current-thread-illegalstateexception-no)

Comment: Please extract relevant parts and leave the rest -- digging into 100's of LoC isn't fun.

Comment: I agree with the remark from @Nikita - this example needs to be cut down into a smaller piece of code. I will try to close it as Too Broad for now.

Comment: Incidentally, I wonder if I could trouble you not to add voting advice and other meta-material to titles here? Titles are exclusively for transmitting the purpose of a question, and should not be used for any other purpose. Asking people to read the whole of a question before voting may encourage some downvoting, but other than that, people will not refrain from voting if you ask them to.